# Perl: size of array in a hash, in another hash

Tags: arrays, perl, hash, multidimensional-array, perl-data-structures

So, I have a hash %HoHoA.
Each top level hash key has a second level hash key as a value.
Each second level hash has arrays-of-arrays as values.

In perl's debugger it looks something like this:

```
0 'Top_key_1'
1 HASH(0x...)
  'Second_Key_1' => ARRAY(0x...)
    0   'string 1'
    1   'string 2'
  'Second_Key_2' => ARRAY(0x...)
    0  ARRAY(0x...)
      0 'string 3'
      1 'string 4'
      2 'string 5'
    1  ARRAY(0x...)
      0 'string 6'
      1 'string 7'
2 'Top_key_2'
```

I'm trying to get the size of each suite's two arrays. In the above
example, Second_Key_2 has two arrays, the 0th one is size 3.

```
my $count1 = $#{$HoHoA{$top_key}{$second_key}[0]}+1;
my $count2 = $#{$HoHoA{$top_key}{$second_key}[1]}+1;
```

and

```
my $count1 = @{$HoHoA{$group}{$suite}[0]};
my $count2 = @{$HoHoA{$group}{$suite}[1]};
```

I get an error message like:
Can't use string ("string 3") as an ARRAY ref while "strict refs" in use

Why am I getting that error message, and what should I do instead?

Comment: Have you read [perldoc perldsc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html) and [perldoc perllol](http://perldoc.perl.org/perllol.html)? Some very similar structures are dissected in detail there.

Comment: Also http://perlmonks.org/?node=References+quick+reference - though you seem to get the idea, but have a slight difference between your data and what you seem to expect.

Answer (score 1):

`$HoHoA{$group}{$suite}[0]` isn't an arrayref; it's a string, thus the error. Maybe you need to debug the code that's building your data structure.

Comment: Though `$HoHoA{$group}{$suite}[1]` is an arrayref.

Answer (score 1):

Run it under the debugger and recursively dump out a data structure, or point therein, with the `x` command.

You can do that programmatically with the `Dumpvalue` module, but it’s much less convenient.

I wish people wouldn’t keep thinking I wrote `perllol` as a joke. ☺

Answer (score 0):

It look like you went one level too deep.
The code below should get you what you want

```
my $count1 = @{$HoHoA{$group}{$suite}};
```

You may also may want to use Data::Dumper to see the
Structure of your object to ensure you are working on the write data format.
use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper($HoHoA);